# How to get lower-level items for runebreaking

Tags: rift

I've got Foraging, Apothecary, and Runecrafting as my professions in Rift.  My character is about level 30 now, but I haven't worked on runecrafting as much as I should as I was leveling.  When I loot items, it says "Requires Runecrafting 76", while my runecrafting skill is only about 35.  Is there a good way to get lower-level items to runebreak, to level up that profession?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a three options for lower level runebreaking I can think up off the top of my head.

1. The first, easiest, and most expensive way is to **buy** items from the **auctioneer** to runebreak.
2. The second, and slowest way, is to make **another character** and send your old gear to your runebreaker character.
3. The third option that is somewhere in the middle is to **craft low level gear** with a weaponsmith/armorsmith character and send it to your runebreaker.

Comment: To add to the last option, if you get hold of an Outfitter, they can take any cloth you have and turn it into cheap boots etc with no extra material costs. Example: http://www.rifthead.com/recipe/1386381847/wool-shoes

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I ended up buying the cheapest runebreakable items that the auction house had, for about 12-15 gold each.  It cost a bit of gold, but now my runecrafting skill level is much better.

Answer (score 1):

Other thing is to ask your lower level **friends/guildies** to send you some of the low drops they don't need (some ppl are nice and have no use for them + some ppl can't sell on auction or just don't want to bother + you can make them some runes later as reward for them).

Also if you weren't doing just quests all the time, you may want to finish the **lower area ones** for some lower level items to runebreak and for rep + achievements.

Last thing I want to recommend is to **keep up your runebreaking up with your level** because I didn't do that and had some hard time getting materials when I ran out of lower level mats for my outfitter - to make them and runebreak them :D.. I also bought few items from AH for runebreaking or just the mats - it's sometimes cheaper. But as you see it's waste of platina when you can just levelup the runecrafting at some time you levelup your character.